# Area of a cyclic polygon maximum when it is a regular polygon

Tags: geometry, inequality, euclidean-geometry, polygons

**My question:** *Let $n$ points $A_1, A_2,\ldots,A_n$ lie on given circle then show that $\operatorname{Area}(A_1A_2\cdots A_n)$ maximum when $A_1A_2\cdots A_n$ is an $n$-regular polygon.*

Comment: This is not a question (note that there is no question mark).  Please expand to explain what it is you are having trouble with (not a command for us to solve your problem).

Comment: Why? AMM and Crux also proposed problem is the same way? @TravisJ

Comment: Dear Dr.Michael Hardy, thank to you for your helping. 

I wonder that: The journals AMM and Crux also proposed problem is the same way above? But why I can not posted my problem at here in the same way???

Comment: Posing a problem is not the same thing as asking a question.

Comment: Why I can not posted my problem at here? Could you show the law ? Dear @TravisJ

Comment: I Think we can proposed own problem?

Comment: Why AMM have subsection Problem and Solution? But here don't have?

Comment: Here there are Questions and Answers (not problems and solutions).  The purpose of this site is to ask questions.  If you just post a problem it does 2 things.  It shows no effort on your part to try to solve the problem (unless you provide detail about what you have tried).  It also gives the impression that you simply want us to do your homework for you.  Not only is this dishonest (when it comes to academic work), but if you just ask others to solve your problems you don't learn much or anything.  It is better to explain what you have done and ask for direction moving forward.

Comment: No, I am electrical engineer, I don't have My homework; I am not a student and I am not a teacher.

Comment: I give my problem by my observation; And I posted own my problem at here same way of AMM and Crux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call the center of the circle $O$.

First, it's clear that none of the angles $\angle A_1OA_2$, $\angle A_2OA_3$,…,$\angle A_nOA_1$ should be greater than $\pi$. If they were, the polygon would be smaller then half of circle $O$. Obviously, this is not maximal.

Let's call $m\angle A_1OA_2=\theta_1$, $m\angle A_2OA_3=\theta_2$,…, $m\angle A_1OA_n=\theta_n$.

The area of the polygon is: $$\frac{r^2}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n \sin\left(\theta_i\right)$$
Note that $\sin(x)$ is concave on $[0,\pi]$. From Jensen's inequality: 
$$\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i\right)\geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \sin\left(\theta_i\right)$$
We know that $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i=2\pi$ so we can deduce the following:
$$n\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\geq \sum_{i=1}^n \sin\left(\theta_i\right)$$

This means that:
$$\frac{r^2}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n \sin\left(\theta_i\right)\leq \frac{nr^2}{2}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)$$

This suggests that the area of the polygon is maximized when $\theta_1, \theta_2, \ldots, \theta_n = \displaystyle\frac{2\pi}{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

**My answer:** Show that if the polygon is not regular, then you can get a larger area by moving a sigle vertex along the circle.

Comment: Thank you dear @Arthur, But, show that area of $(A_1A_2...A_n)$ maximum when $A_1A_2...A_n$ is regular polygon?

Comment: @OaiThanhĐào This answer shows that for any _irregular_ polygon there is always a larger polygon inscribed in the same circle. But no polygon can be larger than the maximal polygon. Hence the maximal polygon can only be the regular one. In fact this is the same idea as the answer you accepted, except that this answer does not contain incorrect statements.

Comment: @DavidK It could be argued that one also needs to show that a maximal polygon does in fact exist. Depending on context and assumptions that may or may not be entirely obvious (for example, there is *no* non-degenerate polygon of *minimal* area).

Comment: @dxiv Good point, although for the minimum it is easy to establish that if the set of cyclical polygons is allowed to include degenerate polygons then those degenerate polygons are minimal (provided that our definition of "area" doesn't allow negative values).

Answer (score 2):

This answer is different from my previous answer, and maybe even better.

If our polygon is not regular, we can find $A_{i-1}$, $A_i$, and $A_{i+1}$, such that $A_i$ is not the midpoint of the arc between $A_{i-1}$ and $A_{i+1}$. Notice that when we move $A_i$ to the midpoint of this arc, the area of the polygon becomes bigger, since the area of $\triangle A_{i-1} A_i A_{i+1}$ increases. Ergo, the maximal polygon is the polygon for which $A_i$ is the midpoint of arc $A_{i-1}A_{i+1}$  for all $i$.

Comment: Haha, that was the argument I wanted to give before getting lost into the details. I goofed.

Comment: `Ergo, the maximal polygon is ...` IMHO this needs more elaborating (just like @Arthur's hint). Moving one vertex at a time to the middle position does indeed increase the area at each step, but it does *not* (generally) lead to the regular polygon in a finite number of steps. Depending on how the next vertex to be moved is chosen, the process may not even converge to the regular polygon. To complete the proof, one would need to show that there *is* a choice of steps that converges to the regular polygon, and that choice yields the largest area among all possible such sequences.

Comment: @dxiv: why? The proof need not be constructive, it just shows that if the polygon is not regular the area is not maximal. So assuming there is indeed a polygon with maximal area, it needs to be regular. Right?

Comment: @zarathustra `assuming there is indeed a polygon with maximal area` That's precisely where I see the difficulty along this line of argumentation. You need to *prove* rather than *assume* that there is such a maximal-area polygon, and that it's unique. Don't get me wrong, I believe that the idea is intuitive and fundamentally sound, but formalizing it into an actual *proof* requires more than an `ergo`.

Comment: @zarathustra--If every inscribed n-gon is either regular or irregular, and the regular n-gon has greater area than any irregular n-gon, and the area of the regular n-gon is unique for a given circle and given n, then doesn't it follow that there is an n-gon with maximum area, and it is the regular n-gon?