# How do I check if there is a proof for a certain theorem?

Tags: proof-writing

Yesterday I proved my first theorem! It's quite dumb and all, but it says that for any number of sides n, the polygon with most area you can inscribe in a circumference is a regular polygon. I haven't found a proof for anything like this, but I'd like to know whether somebody has proved it ever before.

I expect it to be proven, but if not, what could I do with the proof? Is there somewhere I can check for proofs to theorems online, maybe?

Comment: There is no maximum area of an $n$-gon. Is the perimeter fixed?

Comment: I didn't say the maximum area was fixed. I said that the polygon of n sides with maximum area, is for any n, regular. And no, the perimeter is not fixed. The only limitation is that the polygon must be inscribed.

Comment: try a search in google, proofwiki or just [in math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552961/proving-the-regular-n-gon-maximizes-area-for-fixed-perimeter) (check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868026/given-a-polygon-of-n-sides-why-does-the-regular-one-i-e-all-sides-equal-encl) or also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919440/area-of-a-cyclic-polygon-maximum-when-it-is-a-regular-polygon)).

Comment: @Masacroso yep, [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919440/area-of-a-cyclic-polygon-maximum-when-it-is-a-regular-polygon) got me.

Comment: Congratulations for proving something. Even if it's already known - and expect that to be the case for things you prove for quite some time, a **lot** of very smart people have proved a lot of stuff over a long time - it's always an achievement to prove something on one's own.

Comment: I googled "maximum area of n-gon inscribed in circle" and got a long list of good stuff, including this theorem asked and answered on this site.....   I have found that to find something on this site, it's often easier to google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and google it. Otherwise you should go onto MatSciNet or a similar database (accessible through a university library) and do a search, that is search for listed pear reviewed papers that may have already addressed the problem.

Comment: I'm not yet in university yet, is there any other way? I've tried googling it, but nothing seems to be coming up.

Comment: If you don't get any helpful replies, I am happy to do a quick search for you. Let me know.

Comment: It was proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919440/area-of-a-cyclic-polygon-maximum-when-it-is-a-regular-polygon) already. Oh well. At least I've learned some LaTex.

Comment: You can also check books on geometry in a university library (no need to be a student), for example Coxeter Geometry. There will be pdfs online as well. I'd say that someone will have addressed the problem already. Good luck.